Flutter build error: Unsupported class file major version 65 due to JDK version mismatch (?)
I'm currently working on a Flutter project, but encountering build operation errors related to JDK versions. Android toolchain is using JDK 21.0.3, whereas my system has only JDK 18.0.2.1 installed. My JAVA_HOME and env path are configured to use JDK 18.0.2.1. I suspect that this mismatch might be causing errors with tasks such as generateDebugUnitTestConfig for multiple plugins (e.g., flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle, image_picker_android, etc.) (I might be wrong, please correct me if I'm wrong).
I'm encountering an issue when trying to run my Flutter project with the command flutter run. I receive the following error message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy'
Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... 15.3s

Flutter Fix
[!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle.

If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at docs.flutter.dev/go/android-java-gradle-error.

Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter doctor --verbose.

Then, update the Gradle version specified in E:\App
Flutter\learn4_flutter\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be compatible with that Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

What I Tried:

I ran flutter doctor -v, and the output shows that the JDK used by Android toolchain is version 21.0.3. However, I only have JDK version 18.0.2.1 installed on my device.

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011], locale en-US)

• Flutter version 3.19.1 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter

• Upstream repository ``https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

• Framework revision abb292a07e (8 months ago), 2024-02-20 14:35:05 -0800

• Engine revision 04817c99c9

• Dart version 3.3.0

• DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)

• Android SDK at C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

• Platform android-34-ext10, build-tools 34.0.0

• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

• All Android licenses accepted.


I attempted to sync the Gradle project, but I received multiple build operation failures related to tasks for various plugins (e.g., flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle, image_picker_android).

Multiple build operations failed.     

Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.     

Could not create task ':image_picker_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.     

Could not create task ':local_auth_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.     

Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.     

Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.     

Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.     

this and base files have different roots: E:\App-Flutter\learn4_flutter\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.19\android.

Questions:

Is the mismatch between JDK 21.0.3 and 18.0.2.1 the root cause of the error?
Do I need to move my project folder to the path indicated in the error message, or is there a better solution?
How can I ensure that Android toolchain uses the correct JDK version (18.0.2.1) instead of 21.0.3?
HOW CAN I FIX THIS PROBLEM?

addition info:

JAVA_HOME


env path


version check with cmd


java installed on my device


gradle



File gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip 

android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.learn4_flutter"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.learn4_flutter"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}


android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Can you provide build.gradle?

@Alaindeseine I add the build.gradle

I thinks it's a version mismatch between Gradle and installed JAVA version, you can refer to this for matching: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

flutter first finds the android studio one, in case java 21, try setting flutter's java to 17 in:
flutter config --java-dir={YOUR-JAVA-17-HOME}


I recently faced a similar issue and found a solution that worked consistently across all the machines I tested.
When using Android Studio for development, it comes with its own JDK, and you cannot simply override it by installing a different JDK on your machine and setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. For Flutter development, setting the JAVA_HOME variable is unnecessary. Here's the correct way to change the JDK version for Android Studio:
Steps to Change Android Studio's JDK Version

Update the JDK in Android Studio

Open File → Project Structure.
Look for the JDK or JRE section (it may be listed under "SDK Location").
Click the dropdown menu, and you’ll see an option to Download JDK with various versions available.
Download the required version.


Set the JDK Path for Flutter

Once downloaded, copy the path where the JDK was installed.
Use the following Flutter commands to update the JDK path:
flutter config --jdk-dir  # To check the current JDK path
flutter config --jdk-dir "[YOUR_NEW_JDK_PATH]"





And that’s it! Your Flutter environment should now use the updated JDK without any issues.

Use this : flutter config --jdk-dir={YOUR-JAVA-17-HOME}
for me it is : flutter config --jdk-dir=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home

my jdk is 11, 17 solves the problem?

This is a problem in the new version of Android Studio (Ladybug >= 2024.2.1 Patch 2) in not supporting older versions of Flutter.
As Arimateia Oliveira mentions, the command below should work:
flutter config --jdk-dir <path-to-java-sdk-17-home-directory>


"this problem occurs when a dependency does not support Java 21, which Android Studio Ladybug brings by default as share_plus, which requires Java 17. Even if you do not use this package directly, it is very likely that some dependency uses it." (EdsonMello-code)
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/158926#issuecomment-2488475208

